# How to change FPS when using a sprite sheet and AnimationPlayer?

Tags: godot

With AnimatedSprite it is easy to change FPS. Is there a convenient way to do that with AnimationPlayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AnimationPlayer` has a [`playback_speed`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-property-playback-speed) that you can use the way as the [`speed_scale`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html#class-animatedsprite-property-speed-scale) property of the `AnimatedSprite`.

However, there is no way to manipulate the speed of the individual animation themselves. That is, you cannot change the speed of the animations, only the speed of the player.

Suffice to say that the animations are not encoded in frames, but time in seconds instead.

By the way, I remind you that with Property Tracks and Call Method Tracks, the `AnimationPlayer` can manipulate other nodes, including `AnimatedSprite`.

Comment: I am trying  to use Sprite + AnimationPlayer, because normal maps seem to not work with AimatedSprite... EDIT: I have found what I was doing wrong. I m gonna make a question and answer it, I think it might be helpful